# What is the difference between 各 and 毎{ごと}?

Tags: word-choice, prefixes

I think the difference is mainly just a nuance:

- 毎{ごと}・・・each ・・・それぞれの
- 各・・・every・・・すべての

I think 毎 is used mainly with 名詞や動詞

- 「年毎に」
- 「会う人毎に」

Or there is any other difference?

Comment: There is a difference in 毎{まい}〜 and 〜毎{ごと}. If you compare it to それぞれ or 各, I think you compare the preceding 毎{まい}. But the examples you gave are for the suffix 毎{ごと}. You might want consider splitting the question in two: the difference between 毎{まい}〜 and 〜毎{ごと} and your original with 毎{まい}・それぞれ・各

Answer (score 9):

This question is interesting for me. We say `毎年`(every year), `毎日`(everyday), `毎回`/`毎度`(each time), `各人`/`各自`/`各位`(each person), `各国`/`国ごと`(each country), `各地`(each place), `各所`/`各部`(each parts), etc... Also say `各年`, `各回`, `人ごと`, `年毎`, rarely say `各日`, however DON'T say  `毎人`, `毎国`, `毎地`, `各度`.

I think those are decided by common practice and no rigorous rules. You had better look up those words in a dictionary before use. It's irregular.

Answer (score 0):

### 毎~

日本語基本文法事典 (A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar) defines 毎 as:

> a prefix which means 'every (unity of time)'

It is used as a prefix for nouns which express a unit of time (毎日、毎朝、毎回、毎時, etc...). It is mostly used with words of Japanese origin of one or two syllables or shorter words of Chinese origin.

In Hibiya Ryuto's examples that are considered unacceptable (毎人, 毎国, 毎地), the nouns that follow 毎 do not indicate a time or period of time.

- 毎々{まいまい} means 'each time; frequently; always​'.

[Examples](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%AF%8E*)

---

### 各~

各 is a prefix added to nouns to express 'each element of a group'. It is mostly added to words of Chinese origin.

- 各々{おのおの} means 'each'.

[Examples](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%90%84*)